# Installation freeze - 18.04

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I booted Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from a USB to test it before installing it. I decided to install it, and I'm having some problems.
The installer seems to be stuck. It has sat on this screen for quite a while now.

**Screenshot of Installer:**

[image: screenshot of installer]

I can still select a time zone and edit the text in the box, but the buttons are greyed. I can still use the rest of the system perfectly fine (except for some reason the system monitor wouldn't open). I think it already did partitioning, so I don't know if it's "safe" to reboot. I have Windows 10 already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue installing mine on a MSI GL62M 7RDX few days ago. What I did was reboot the system, go directly to `Install Ubuntu`, delete the previous partition I created in `Try Ubuntu`, and continue with installation.

Comment: YES! IT WORKED! You are awesome, thank you so much for your speedy answer.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Choosing not to connect to the WiFi in one of the steps before solved it for me. You can always update the OS and the packages later with `aptitude` or similar tools.